# Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) Applicability

Tags: bayesian, bic

**Question**
Can you compare BIC results between two models that are the same except for the removal of, say, a block of items from one of the models?

**Situation**
I'm still in the process of understanding how the BIC is supposed to be used and I want to make sure I am applying it correctly within my situation.

Situation:

- I have a large survey that is designed to measure 3 latent constructs.
- The survey has 6 sections, each with 12 items, so there are 72 items in total.
- My goal is to trim the survey down to only 4 or 5 sections to reduce the time it takes to complete

Here is an examples of the measurement model diagram for models that I am trying to compare. Each time I remove a section of items, the BIC number goes way down. I am not sure if this is because the smaller model is actually a better model or if it is just an artifact of the BIC calculation being particularly sensitive to how parameters there are.
[image: Full Model]
[image: Model with one section eliminated]
[image: Model with two sections eliminated]